# How to construct sed command to replace either of the words?

Tags: bash, sed

What I am trying to do is replace words **foo** or **bar**, may or may not exist in the input string, with hyphen(`-`) and I came up with this but it is not working as expected.

```
> echo "foo,baz" | sed 's/\(foo\|bar\)/-/g'
> foo,baz <-- Why is foo not replaced with hyphen here?
```

I am able to achieve what I want as below but I am curious as what is wrong with the above.

```
> echo "foo,baz" | sed 's/\(foo\)/-/g' | sed 's/\(bar\)//g'
> -,baz
```

**EDIT**: I am trying this on Mac OS with zsh.

Comment: the 1st set of code generates `-,baz` for me; what version of `sed` are you running?  also, I don't understand how the 1st set of code manages to replace `baz` with `bar` ... ????

Comment: the subject and description mention `'words'` but the code you've provided will replace `'strings'`; as currently written your code will replace `afoob` with `a-b` ... is this what you want, or do you only want to replace (whole) words `foo` or `bar` (in which case `afoob` will remain as `afoob`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso How do I get sed version on Mac OS? I purposely gave `baz` in the input string and `bar` in the sed. My expectation is that it should replace `foo` and do nothing with `baz` as it doesn't match with `bar`.

Comment: @markp-fuso Poor choice of words. What I am looking for is string replacement and not word replacement.

Comment: Try `echo "foo,baz" | sed -E 's/(foo|bar)/-/g'`(-E Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions). Should work with GNU and BSD sed.

Comment: the ouput from your 1st set of code shows `foo,bar` (`baz` replaced with `bar`); at this point I'm guessing this is a typo on your behalf?  as for the `sed` version ... with `GNU sed` it's `sed --version`; macos is known to have some old and/or oddball versions of some binaries (examples: `sed` and `awk`); short of getting `GNU sed` installed (via homebrew?) you could try: `sed 's/foo/-/g; s/bar/-/g'`

Comment: @AndreWildberg That worked. Thanks. I did try this before but like this `echo "foo,bar" | sed -E 's/\(foo\|bar\)/-/g'`. Now I know the mistake I made.

Comment: Legacy `sed` does not support alteration as you have used it. You can use `sed -E 's/foo|bar/-/g'` or use Perl|Ruby here.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `bash`?

Answer (score 1):

in your first command, the pattern `\(foo\|bar\)` doesn't seem to work as expected,it's because sed uses Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) by default, and the alternation operator `|` is treated as a literal character,so to make it work, you can either escape it or use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) with the `-E` flag!

in first command, just remove the escaped parentheses and directly use the `foo\|bar` pattern for alternation.

```
echo "foo,baz" | sed 's/foo\|bar/-/g'
```

or

```
echo "foo,baz" | sed 's/\(foo\|bar\)/-/g'
```

and using `-E` flag for Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), it replaces "foo" with a hyphen ("-") using the first sed command and then removes "bar" using the second sed command.:

```
echo "foo,baz" | sed -E 's/(foo|bar)/-/g'
```

Comment: For short words, think using *word boundary*: `echo "barrier,foo,bar,baz,football" | sed -E 's/\b(foo|bar)\b/-/g'`

Answer (score 0):

Close, need to escape the or as well (escape everything really):

```
echo "foo,baz" | sed 's/\(foo\)\|\(bar\)/-/g'
```